# Locked out while setting up nginx

Tags: sudo, nginx, centos-7, sudoers, digital-ocean

It's my first time trying to setup a web server.

I was trying to set up a Digital Ocean Droplet running CentOS.

During nginx setup, I 'accidentally' changed the permission of '/' to the nginx user, so now I can't access anything; sudo fails with:

```
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is owned by uid 997, should be 0
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

Unfortunately, by following Digital Ocean's guides, I disabled root login, so I can't find a way to change the permissions back. I've tried to

```
su - nginx
```

but I couldn't find the password of that user, so that won't help.

Is there a known default password when nginx initializes, or perhaps another solution? Must I shut my server down, and get a new one?

Comment: Did you disable root login completely or only over SSH? If you still have regular root login enabled, you can use Digital Ocean's web console.

Comment: You're right, I disabled it only over SSH. However after I reset my root pwd, and tried to set a new one over the web console, i got
    `authentication token manipulation error`
multiple times. It seems to be an unsolved problem, so again, i guess I'm out of options.